# How can I add a color picker to a custom Gutenberg block which includes the default system palette from theme.json?

Tags: block-editor, color-picker, theme.json

Do I need to use the `ColorGradientControl` component to add this interface to a custom block, even if gradients are deactivated by theme.json?

[image]